# How to Install OpenWRT on LinkSys WRT54G v6?

Tags: openwrt, linksys

Does anyone know how to install OpenWRT on LinkSys WRT54G v5 Wireless Router?

I know the installation procedure, but just want to know a stable firmware of OpenWRT for WRT54G v6?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you can found the answer from below links:

http://wiki.openwrt.org/inbox/park

http://www.bitsum.com/openwiking/owbase/WRT54G5_CFE/#h8